# Can I still link a Dragonvale park to Facebook after I get the park ID?

Tags: dragonvale

My son's park is level 32, on a Kindle. He's put a lot of time and effort into his dragons and he loves the game. Long story short, his Kindle is dying. He did not have a FB when we started the park, but I thought it was possible to back up the park with help from Backflip if I found the park "id". So, I clicked the button for Park ID on the settings screen.

Now my son is old enough for a Facebook, and we set him up with one and I thought we could use it to save his dragons. Unfortunately, the "connect with Facebook" is no longer an option, or at least the "connect with Facebook" button is now gone, I think because I clicked to get the Park ID.

Is there any way I can associate this park with a Facebook? In a day or two his kindle will die completely, and he will lose more than six months' continual effort and a bunch of rare dragons. (And, if you can't ever again associate the park with FB once you get the ID, and you can't use the ID to back anything up or retrieve progress, why do they even have an option to let the user get the ID at all???)

Thanks, we're desperate and he's very very sad and worried for the dragons.

Comment: Hi Norma. While I'm not sure how to transfer from the Kindle to Facebook, I did some reading around and it seems that emailing the support guys (support@backflipstudios.com) has been helpful for people with similar problems. It might be worth you trying that in the meantime, whilst waiting for another possible answer.

Comment: I also found the following statement: *"If you CONNECT your Local game with a Facebook Account or Game Center, your Dragonvale Park will be saved. If NOT connected, BFS advice is to contact them first, for help to save your game, else it be lost."*

Comment: See this answer http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/149682/65678 which quotes the BackFlip FAQ on the matter.