# Can I transfer a Dragonvale world between accounts?

Tags: dragonvale

I foolishly let my child try Dragonvale... but on a Kindle Fire device I must now return.  Can the world be packaged and transferred to an Android or iOS device account?

On Kindle Fire specifically it appears each "Free Time" child gets their own world, are these parks transferable once the kids reach the age of majority and/or get their own Kindle?

Comment: On iOS, the world is stored on their server, linked via your GameCenter ID.  Not sure how it works on Kindle, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Android Device [FAQ](http://www.backflipstudios.com/help/androidfaq/) from Backflip, you can transfer a "local" park to be a "facebook" park, using the options menu within the game.  A "facebook" park can be signed into from a different Android device (but not from an iOS device).

If you have an existing Facebook park, you'll be prompted to ask which park to keep.  Parks cannot be converted back to local parks, and you can only have one Facebook park.

Answer (score 1):

In Dragonvale, there are two modes of access: 1) local mode, and 2) server mode. For a user to use "server mode", they *must* connect to Facebook. If the user has played without doing so, their Dragonvale game information is stored only on local mode, and cannot be transferred. If the game was connected, then the user can access that park on any device, so long as the user installs the Dragonvale app, and then signs in to their saved server information by connecting to Facebook.

If your children signed into their Facebook pages, then their game is saved on the server, and they will be able to retrieve them. If they have not connected the game to Facebook, then they will not be able to save their park information, and will have to start again when they start playing on a new device.

Comment: In local mode, then, the park data is in the storage the app uses.  Has anyone tried copying that data to a different device in the same family?

Comment: The BackFlip FAQ implies that a local park can be transferred to Facebook, but not back.  Note: these are not children that will have facebook pages any time soon.